# media element playback a portion and wait

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

How can I set my MediaElement (Silverlight) to play an audio file when it has some data (for example 10 % of the streamed file) ?

I want to start playback immediately after a little portion has buffered, then, if the application had no data, just pause the playback and wait. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance,

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I think this is supported by the MediaElement. You just have to specify thru one of its properties whether it should Begin automatically.